# Csharp with node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I wanted to send data from csharp to a webpage live without having to reload or anything annoying like that so I decided to use Node.JS and socket.io

I am totally new to socket.io and node.js so correct me if this isnt how it works...
1) I sent data from my Csharp application using the code below.

```
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Plus.HabboHotel.Roleplay.Extra.SocketIO
{
    public static class SocketIOManager
    {
        public static void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            var socket = IO.Socket("http://127.0.0.1:400");

            socket.On(Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
            {
                socket.Emit("emu_msg", @"Hello from PlusEMU");
                socket.Disconnect();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

2) The Node.JS app.js picks it up

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

io.on('emu_msg', function(socket){
  console.log('emu message received?');
});

http.listen(400, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:400');
});
```

Now on the node.js console I should be getting "emu message received" should I not? I am not receiving that
Does anybody know why?

I do receive the 'a user connected' when visiting the webpage that uses the code below

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:400');
    socket.on('emu_msg', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    </script>
```

But when sending a message with csharp I don't get anything, not even the user connect message, am I missing something here? And I don't get the alert on the webpage when sending with csharp either.

Comment: I use SocketIoClient.Net library in csharp to send data

Comment: Maybe you want an ASP.NET MVC application with SignalR? That way you don't need to learn Node nor socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the client you should be listening for the message on the socket.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('emu_msg', function(msg){
    console.log('emu message received?');
  });
});
```

see: [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#emit(name:string[,-%E2%80%A6]):socket) for more information